# Service created in VB .NET not starting

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

We have service developed in Visul Basic .NET. This service utilizes some COM objects provided by SAP to access SAP database. This has been working fine till yesterday. On this Sunday, we upgraded the SAP system, and subsequently all other programs were also re-builded using the new DLL files (for the COM object). We tried doing the same for the service also. But it is not starting now.

When started, it shows a message saying service terminated unexpectedly. This is probably due to the fact that it is not able to load the requisite DLL file.

Please help on how to correct this situation.

Regards,
Rahul Jain

Answer (score 1):

Did you re-add the SAP dll as a reference? I'd try blowing away the current reference and re-adding. Perhaps the .net wrapper for the com object needs to be re-created?

What version of .net are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5. I've tried removing and adding the reference again, but nothing happened.

Comment: Too bad. Have you tried with the old dll? Sounds like you might need to call SAP for support.

Comment: Lets look at it from a different prespective. When it starts, it shows terminated unexpectedly. I know it is throwing some error, but what - I don't know? Other programs utilizing same DLL Files works fine (they are normal windows form program - not services). I have put a try-catch in main also, but still no error message. How can I catch this exception?

Comment: We resolved the problem. It was discovered that the DLL files were not installed properly.

Thanks a lot for your help.